# Python Time Problem

Tags: python, time

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this.

I'm trying to run a python script for a set duration. And every 1/10 of the duration I need it to run something. The problem is this step can take any amount of time to complete. I cannot go over the maximum duration set at the start.

Example:
Duration 20 hours

Interval = 20/10 = 2 hours (This can change if it needs to)

Every two hours it runs function(). function() takes between 0-60 minutes to complete. And then it sleeps. How can I make it so that it continues to run 9 more times, but doesn't go over the max duration?

Comment: Why not to simply use global timer? For example start it at the very begining and simply check it value whenever you need it.

Comment: You can check out `signal.alarm` to use signals. This way a SIGALRM is generated over a given interval, and you can setup your signal handler to call `function`. Also check out `signal.setitimer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use signals. The idea is you set a signal handler to get called when a SIGALRM is generated. In the signal handler you can call `function`. Then you reset the alarm and do it again. This is a basic example just to give you an idea.

```
import signal
...
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)  # set the signal handler
signal.alarm(interval)                        # set the alarm
...
def alarm_handler(signum, stack):
    # call function
    function()
```

Once the alarm goes off, you call `function()` and then reset the alarm:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler)
signal.alarm(interval)
```

Or you can use `signal.setitimer` to automatically configure interval alarms, however I am not sure how that will work with large timeslices (its used for microsleeps).

NOTE: You must call signal.alarm() from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Fork a subprocess to do the actual job; kill the job if it exceeds your run-time limit.